# Python Flask Node.js failed to load resources 404

Tags: python, node.js, flask, http-status-code-404

Hi I am trying to send data from node to python. I read this is possible via 2 server with express and Flask. However when I run the code I receive an error (see below)

Python script

```
from flask import Flask, request
import json

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return "Flask server"

@app.route('/postdata', methods = ['POST'])
def postdata():
    data = request.get_json()
    print(data)
    # do something with this data variable that contains the data from the node server
    return json.dumps({"newdata":"hereisthenewdatayouwanttosend"})

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(port=5000)
```

The Node script

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var request = require('request-promise');

var app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.get('/postdatatoFlask', async function (req, res) {
    var data = { 
        data1: "foo",
        data2: "bar"
    }

    var options = {
        method: 'POST',
        uri: 'http://localhost:3000/postdata',
        body: data,
        json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
    };

    var returndata;
    var sendrequest = await request(options)
    .then(function (parsedBody) {
        console.log(parsedBody); 
        returndata = parsedBody; 
    })
    .catch(function (err) {
        console.log(err);
    });

    res.send(returndata);
});

app.listen(3000);
```

However if I now try to execute the post request with 
http://localhost:3000/postdatatoFlask I get the 404 error

PS C:\Users\danie\Desktop\nodepythonproject> node nodepython
{ StatusCodeError: 404 - "\n\n\n\nError\n\n\n

```
Cannot POST /postdata
```

\n\n\n"
    at new StatusCodeError (C:\Users\danie\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\errors.js:32:15)
    at Request.plumbing.callback (C:\Users\danie\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:104:33)
    at Request.RP$callback [as _callback] (C:\Users\danie\node_modules\request-promise-core\lib\plumbing.js:46:31)
    at Request.self.callback (C:\Users\danie\node_modules\request\request.js:185:22)
    at emitTwo (events.js:126:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:214:7)
    at Request. (C:\Users\danie\node_modules\request\request.js:1157:10)
    at emitOne (events.js:116:13)
    at Request.emit (events.js:211:7)
    at IncomingMessage. (C:\Users\danie\node_modules\request\request.js:1079:12)
    at Object.onceWrapper (events.js:313:30)
    at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1064:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)
  name: 'StatusCodeError',
  statusCode: 404,
  message: '404 - "\n\n\n\nError\n\n\n

```
Cannot POST /postdata
```

\n\n\n"',
  error: '\n\n\n\nError\n\n\n

```
Cannot POST /postdata
```

\n\n\n',
  options:
   { method: 'POST',
     uri: 'http://localhost:3000/postdata',
     body: { data1: 'foo', data2: 'bar' },
     json: true,
     callback: [Function: RP$callback],
     transform: undefined,
     simple: true,
     resolveWithFullResponse: false,
     transform2xxOnly: false },
  response:
   IncomingMessage {
     _readableState:
      ReadableState {
        objectMode: false,
        highWaterMark: 16384,
        buffer: [Object],
        length: 0,
        pipes: null,
        pipesCount: 0,
        flowing: true,
        ended: true,
        endEmitted: true,
        reading: false,
        sync: true,
        needReadable: false,
        emittedReadable: false,
        readableListening: false,
        resumeScheduled: false,
        destroyed: false,
        defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
        awaitDrain: 0,
        readingMore: false,
        decoder: null,
        encoding: null },
     readable: false,
     domain: null,
     _events:
      { end: [Array],
        close: [Array],
        data: [Function],
        error: [Function] },
     _eventsCount: 4,
     _maxListeners: undefined,
     socket:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 175,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Object],
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 22,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 392 },
     connection:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 175,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Object],
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 22,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 392 },
     httpVersionMajor: 1,
     httpVersionMinor: 1,
     httpVersion: '1.1',
     complete: true,
     headers:
      { 'x-powered-by': 'Express',
        'content-security-policy': 'default-src \'self\'',
        'x-content-type-options': 'nosniff',
        'content-type': 'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'content-length': '148',
        date: 'Fri, 21 Sep 2018 17:36:52 GMT',
        connection: 'close' },
     rawHeaders:
      [ 'X-Powered-By',
        'Express',
        'Content-Security-Policy',
        'default-src \'self\'',
        'X-Content-Type-Options',
        'nosniff',
        'Content-Type',
        'text/html; charset=utf-8',
        'Content-Length',
        '148',
        'Date',
        'Fri, 21 Sep 2018 17:36:52 GMT',
        'Connection',
        'close' ],
     trailers: {},
     rawTrailers: [],
     upgrade: false,
     url: '',
     method: null,
     statusCode: 404,
     statusMessage: 'Not Found',
     client:
      Socket {
        connecting: false,
        _hadError: false,
        _handle: null,
        _parent: null,
        _host: 'localhost',
        _readableState: [Object],
        readable: false,
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 8,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        _writableState: [Object],
        writable: false,
        allowHalfOpen: false,
        _bytesDispatched: 175,
        _sockname: null,
        _pendingData: null,
        _pendingEncoding: '',
        server: null,
        _server: null,
        parser: null,
        _httpMessage: [Object],
        _idleNext: null,
        _idlePrev: null,
        _idleTimeout: -1,
        [Symbol(asyncId)]: 22,
        [Symbol(bytesRead)]: 392 },
     _consuming: true,
     _dumped: false,
     req:
      ClientRequest {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        output: [],
        outputEncodings: [],
        outputCallbacks: [],
        outputSize: 0,
        writable: true,
        _last: true,
        upgrading: false,
        chunkedEncoding: false,
        shouldKeepAlive: false,
        useChunkedEncodingByDefault: true,
        sendDate: false,
        _removedConnection: false,
        _removedContLen: false,
        _removedTE: false,
        _contentLength: null,
        _hasBody: true,
        _trailer: '',
        finished: true,
        _headerSent: true,
        socket: [Object],
        connection: [Object],
        _header: 'POST /postdata HTTP/1.1\r\nhost: localhost:3000\r\naccept: application/json\r\ncontent-type: application/json\r\ncontent-length: 29\r\nConnection: close\r\n\r\n',
        _onPendingData: [Function: noopPendingOutput],
        agent: [Object],
        socketPath: undefined,
        timeout: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        path: '/postdata',
        _ended: true,
        res: [Circular],
        aborted: undefined,
        timeoutCb: null,
        upgradeOrConnect: false,
        parser: null,
        maxHeadersCount: null,
        [Symbol(outHeadersKey)]: [Object] },
     request:
      Request {
        domain: null,
        _events: [Object],
        _eventsCount: 5,
        _maxListeners: undefined,
        method: 'POST',
        uri: [Object],
        body: '{"data1":"foo","data2":"bar"}',
        readable: true,
        writable: true,
        explicitMethod: true,
        _qs: [Object],
        _auth: [Object],
        _oauth: [Object],
        _multipart: [Object],
        _redirect: [Object],
        _tunnel: [Object],
        _rp_resolve: [Function],
        _rp_reject: [Function],
        _rp_promise: [Object],
        _rp_callbackOrig: undefined,
        callback: [Function],
        _rp_options: [Object],
        headers: [Object],
        setHeader: [Function],
        hasHeader: [Function],
        getHeader: [Function],
        removeHeader: [Function],
        localAddress: undefined,
        pool: {},
        dests: [],
        __isRequestRequest: true,
        _callback: [Function: RP$callback],
        proxy: null,
        tunnel: false,
        setHost: true,
        originalCookieHeader: undefined,
        _disableCookies: true,
        _jar: undefined,
        port: '3000',
        host: 'localhost',
        path: '/postdata',
        _json: true,
        httpModule: [Object],
        agentClass: [Object],
        agent: [Object],
        _started: true,
        href: 'http://localhost:3000/postdata',
        req: [Object],
        ntick: true,
        response: [Circular],
        originalHost: 'localhost:3000',
        originalHostHeaderName: 'host',
        responseContent: [Circular],
        _destdata: true,
        _ended: true,
        _callbackCalled: true },
     toJSON: [Function: responseToJSON],
     caseless: Caseless { dict: [Object] },
     read: [Function],
     body: '\n\n\n\nError\n\n\n

```
Cannot POST /postdata
```

\n\n\n' } }

Comment: if you navigate to the '/' endpoint, does it return "Flask server" as expected?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your Flask server is listening to port 5000, but your postdatatoFlask method is POSTing to port 3000.

Change this code:

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://localhost:3000/postdata',
    body: data,
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};
```

to this:

```
var options = {
    method: 'POST',
    uri: 'http://localhost:5000/postdata',
    body: data,
    json: true // Automatically stringifies the body to JSON
};
```

Comment: Thank so much for your help. That was indeed the issue.